NGINX Configuration: Redirecting /app to app.php for a symphony application
I'm currently working on an NGINX configuration for a symphony application. I'm trying to set up a rule where any request to /app should be served by app.php. However, I'm having some trouble getting this to work.
Here's my current configuration:
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  *.host.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/_error.log;

    root   /var/www/html/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        # rewrite all to app.php
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # PHP-FPM configuration
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}



With this configuration, I'm expecting that when a user navigates to http://*.host.com/app, NGINX should serve the app.php file. However, this is not happening.
@ChrisHaas did you mean something like the below:
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  *.host.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/_error.log;

    root   /var/www/html/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /app/ {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        # rewrite all to app.php
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # PHP-FPM configuration
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}


it returned a 404 
The application is accessible if I remove the /app from the URL and just go with site.host.com/login/ with the current setup it routs at the backend => site.host.com/app.php/login/. However we require to have something like =>site.host.com/app/login/


Wouldn’t you just do location /app{}, since “starts with” is the default? Or location = /app{} if you want only that route. The inner directive can probably just be try_files app.php =404;, possibly with root adjustment. Also, rewrite is generally for 301/302, I don’t think you’d use that. If you are coming from Apache, this is a big difference between the two config styles.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.
